# Why can't I change the opacity of h1 element back to 1 after changing opacity of html element to 0.5?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I added a background image to my html element in css so it expands with the size of the web browser. I changed the opacity in this html element to 0.5. I want to change the child elements (specifically h1, and paragraph elements) back to an opacity of 1 so the text is not transparent. It doesn't work. Please help :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <p id ="topBar"></p>

    <h1>Heading</h1>

    <h3>Name</h3>

    <p> 
        Paragraph
    </p>

    <h3>Heading</h3>

    <p>More text</p>

    <h3>Send us an email!</h3>

    <form>
        <input style ="width:200px" type="email" placeholder ="Email" name="email"><br><br>
        <textarea style ="height:100px;width:200px"placeholder = "Message" name="message"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value ="Send" name="send">
    </form>

    <p id ="bottomBar"></p>
</body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
html {

background: url(pen.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
background-size: cover;


font-family: Garamond;
text-align: center;

opacity: 0.5;

}

h1 {

opacity: 1;
 }
```

Comment: @LaurIvan Nope. The h1 rule is more specific than the html rule so it applies.

Comment: the entire html document has an opacity directive, it affects everything regardless of specificity or precedence. @LaurIvan adding !important does nothing. you need to set the lower opacity only on specific elements.

Comment: @SLowLoris but how? h1 is nested inside html hence according to css priority the rules of h1 should override that of html

Comment: @geeksal opacity can't be overridden. if you have an element with an opacity of 0.5 and a child in that element with an opacity of 0.5, the child element will have an opacity of 0.25. it already has a reduced opacity from its parent and a further reduction from its own directive. pretty straightforward

Comment: @SLowLoris thanks i don't know that

Answer (score 2):

By default if the parent has opacity applied to it then all the child elements also take the same opacity. Even if you make the child elements as opacity:1 it won't work.
In your case 'html' has opacity:0.5 so its child i.e 'h1' having opacity:1 will still have 0.5 opacity.

For you problem there are 2 solutions:-
1. Make the background image i.e. 'pen.jpg' slightly transparent through a photo editing software like Photoshop.
2. Use the background image in 'after' pseudocode. i.e.

```
html::after {
      content: "";
      background: url(pen.jpg);
      opacity:0.5;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;   
}
```

Any one of the above will work for you.

Comment: Wasn't my answer correct? Why the negative vote?

Comment: Downvote is not from me, but I think it was due to this sentence: `In your case 'html' has opacity:0.5 so its child i.e 'h1' having opacity:1 won't do any difference.`  But actually if you have an opacity 0.5 element inside another opacity 0.5 element, the effect will be 0.25 opacity, so there is a difference. Maybe you could edit that sentence...

Comment: Thanks @gregn3. I edited my sentence.

Comment: I think that's correct otherwise so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the opacity of the parent to `0.5` , all the child elements will get that opacity. i suggest you use a transparent img as background instead OR you could give that background to a pseudo-element.

( i used background-color for example purposes but you can use `background-image` and `opacity:0.5` instead. it still works the same )

```css
html {




font-family: Garamond;
text-align: center;


position:relative;


}
html:before {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   
  content:"";
  z-index:-1;
}

h1 {

opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
 <p id ="topBar"></p>

    <h1>Heading</h1>

    <h3>Name</h3>

    <p> 
        Paragraph
    </p>

    <h3>Heading</h3>

    <p>More text</p>

    <h3>Send us an email!</h3>

    <form>
        <input style ="width:200px" type="email" placeholder ="Email" name="email"><br><br>
        <textarea style ="height:100px;width:200px"placeholder = "Message" name="message"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value ="Send" name="send">
    </form>

    <p id ="bottomBar"></p>
```

Comment: to clarify even further: setting the opacity to 0.5 on a parent div and 0.4 on a paragraph inside that div will result in a opacity of 0.5*0.4=0.2 on the child paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply background to body element instead of html. because all of the visible content is inside in the body tag

```css
body{
 background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);


font-family: Garamond;
text-align: center;

opacity: 0.5;

}
h1 {

opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <p id ="topBar"></p>

    <h1>Heading</h1>

    <h3>Name</h3>

    <p> 
        Paragraph
    </p>

    <h3>Heading</h3>
 
    <p>More text</p>

    <h3>Send us an email!</h3>

    <form>
        <input style ="width:200px" type="email" placeholder ="Email" name="email"><br><br>
        <textarea style ="height:100px;width:200px"placeholder = "Message" name="message"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value ="Send" name="send">
    </form>

    <p id ="bottomBar"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Opacity does not work in this particular case because it inherit from his parent and cant be overwritten.

I changed your background by `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);` and then there is no need to change the opacity of the text anymore.

This is the most simple way of changing it, only using the opacity of the background.

[JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hxwnjc9u/1/)

```css
html {

background: url(pen.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
background-size: cover;


font-family: Garamond;
text-align: center;

background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);

}
```

```html
<body>

    <p id ="topBar"></p>

    <h1>Heading</h1>

    <h3>Name</h3>

    <p> 
        Paragraph
    </p>

    <h3>Heading</h3>

    <p>More text</p>

    <h3>Send us an email!</h3>

    <form>
        <input style ="width:200px" type="email" placeholder ="Email" name="email"><br><br>
        <textarea style ="height:100px;width:200px"placeholder = "Message" name="message"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value ="Send" name="send">
    </form>

    <p id ="bottomBar"></p>
</body>
```